# SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER) is screw up

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I’m trying to investigate for which reason sometime my service SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER) is screwed up and doesn’t respond, producing an error in my SSRS reports. When the users run their report they get an ambiguous and confusing error message like: `Server Error in ‘/Reports’ application`.

This problem was resolved only by stopping and restarting the service.  It comes only a few times, but I don't want to get it again.

The stability of the reporting is the first priority for our team. I want to know the reason or how can we prevent this error in the future.

Comment: Have you looked to see if there is any information in the log file? The user purposely does not see the cause of the error as a protection against a hacker. Look in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles folder and check the ReportServerService_<datetime>.txt file that is near the time you are having problems. Look for errors in the file. Also you might check the Windows Event log for an error involving your report server.

Comment: Second the comment above. As it stands, the question isn't quite answerable I'm afraid, we need more info.